# SQL Server - Substring part of a column in between specific text

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    [message] NVARCHAR(100) NULL,
)
INSERT INTO test
    values
   ('Location set to: Loc1, Order: 1, item: shirt-red.large, company: 01, store: 01'),
   ('Location set to: Loc1, Order: 1, item: shirt-red.medium, company: 01, store: 01'), 
   ('Location set to: Loc2, Order: 220, item: shirt-blue.small, company: 01, store: 089'),
   ('Location set to: Loc2, Order: 220, item: shirt-blue.medium, company: 01, store: 089')
```

In SQL Server (2016), I'm trying to extract the full item string from the above column (e.g. `'shirt-red.large'`, `'shirt-blue.small'` etc), using `CHARINDEX` to search for `'Item: '` and `', '`, but I'm getting following error

> "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Is this something to do with the `', '` being present multiple times in the string? What would be the best way to isolate the item as a result?

Comment: That error feels like you used your parameters in the wrong order. Could you post your query?

Comment: Store the attributes in separate columns.

Comment: The main mistake is storing what looks like it should be *structured* data as plain text. Even if you have different attributes, for example, an XML format would be far more helpful and get you ~95% towards having a simple solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on 2016, here's another option via `string_split()`

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=94f52909baa15e3b1fb51543eec9a3d2)**

```
Select Item = ltrim(rtrim(replace(b.value,'item:','')))
 From  Test A
 Cross Apply string_split([message],',') b
 where charindex('item:',value)>0
```

**Returns**

```
Item
shirt-red.large
shirt-red.medium
shirt-blue.small
shirt-blue.medium
```

**Note:** Use `Outer Apply` if you want to see NULLs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code is, but this should work

```
replace(substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]),len([message]) - charindex(', company',[message])),',','')
```

Or without the item

```
left(substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]) + 6,99),charindex(',',substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]) + 6,99)) - 1)
```

Here it is in action:

```
declare @test TABLE ( [message] NVARCHAR(100) NULL)

INSERT INTO @test
values
('Location set to: Loc1, Order: 1, item: shirt-red.large, company: 01, store: 01'),
('Location set to: Loc1, Order: 1, item: shirt-red.medium, company: 01, store: 01'), 
('Location set to: Loc2, Order: 220, item: shirt-blue.small, company: 01, store: 089'),
('Location set to: Loc2, Order: 220, item: shirt-blue.medium, company: 01, store: 089')

select 
    withItem = replace(substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]),len([message]) - charindex(', company',[message])),',','')
    ,withoutItem = left(substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]) + 6,99),charindex(',',substring([message],charindex('item: ',[message]) + 6,99)) - 1)
from @test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([message],
    CHARINDEX('item: ', [message])+6,
    CHARINDEX(',',message,CHARINDEX('item: ', [message]))-CHARINDEX('item: ', [message])-6)
FROM test
```